# Getting a value of every item in a json file

Tags: python, json, file

So i want to get all of the `prc` values from this json file and add them together.
I was trying for awhile but none of my ideas worked out

`file.json`

```
{
    "prcprice": 10,
    "983712735957229578": {
        "wallet": 693896,
        "prc": 70006
    },
    "453209412102782986": {
        "wallet": 69410,
        "prc": 301
    },
    "475293506295037952": {
        "wallet": 9999,
        "prc": 1000
    }
}
```

Comment: What exactly did you try. What output did you get? Please show your code

Comment: Please, check [ask]. Post your best attempt at solving the task at hand.

Comment: Something like `prcList = [[k,v.get('prc')] for k,v in data.items() if type(v) is dict]` assuming `data = json.load(open('file.json'))`

Answer (score 0):

Didn't understand if you want to calculate "prcprice" if not just paste "pass" in except statement instead of "value = data[key]". Note that I named json dict as "data".

```
values = []
for key in data:
    try:
        value = data[key].get('prc')
    except AttributeError:
        value = data[key]
    values.append(value)
res = sum(values)
print(values)
print(res)
```